# Migrating two columns in SQL script to the db of my rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I have a SQL script that has four columns and about 100 records. I only need two columns. I want to transfer the two columns into my seeds.rb file so that I can have these records in my db when I deploy my app. What would be the easiest way possible to do this? How would it look in my seeds.rb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is get the database in the format you want, and then create a database dump of some sort. MySQL makes this easier than Sqlite. Put the `INSERT` statements into your file like this:

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO `example` (`abbreviation`,`name`)
   VALUES
   ('ABC', 'Alphabet Broadcasting Company'),
   ('DEF', 'Denver Echo Factory'),
   ('GHI', 'Gimbal Helper Industries')
 ")
```

Although `seeds.rb` is a handy way of pre-populating certain critical things, like essential administrators or lookup tables for countries, it does become difficult to maintain over time as `seeds.rb` must always conform to the latest schema.

It may be easier to simply deploy a seed Sqlite file and migrate that instead. With MySQL you typically deploy and load in a seed database dump to get things started, then migrate and enhance as required.

Comment: Thanks. I actually just ended up copy and pasting what I wanted into seeds.rb. It was only 100 records... not too bad ;)